# Flatten layer of PyTorch build by sequential container

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to build a cnn by sequential container of PyTorch, my problem is I cannot figure out how to flatten the layer.

```
main = nn.Sequential()
self._conv_block(main, 'conv_0', 3, 6, 5)
main.add_module('max_pool_0_2_2', nn.MaxPool2d(2,2))
self._conv_block(main, 'conv_1', 6, 16, 3)
main.add_module('max_pool_1_2_2', nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)) 
main.add_module('flatten', make_it_flatten)
```

What should I put in the "make_it_flatten"?
I tried to flatten the main but it do not work, main do not exist something call view

```
main = main.view(-1, 16*3*3)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but you can simply create your own `nn.Module` that flattens any input, which you can then add to the `nn.Sequential()` object:

```
class Flatten(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return x.view(x.size()[0], -1)
```

The `x.size()[0]` will select the batch dim, and `-1` will compute all remaining dims to fit the number of elements, thereby flattening any tensor/Variable.

And using it in `nn.Sequential`:

```
main = nn.Sequential()
self._conv_block(main, 'conv_0', 3, 6, 5)
main.add_module('max_pool_0_2_2', nn.MaxPool2d(2,2))
self._conv_block(main, 'conv_1', 6, 16, 3)
main.add_module('max_pool_1_2_2', nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)) 
main.add_module('flatten', Flatten())
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to flatten the layer is not to create the new module and to add that module to the main via `main.add_module('flatten', Flatten())`.

```
class Flatten(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, input):
        return input.view(input.size(0), -1)
```

Instead, just a simple, `out = inp.reshape(inp.size(0), -1)`  inside `forward` of your model is faster as I showed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56771143/5884955).